# SharePoint 2013 MySites: Users unable to create mysites (personal site)

Tags: 2013, my-site

I am testing out an on prem dev farm with **April CU** I am attempting to create the Mysite web app, sc so my user can self-create their personal sites. With PS script I have been able to repeat this a few times but without success. None of my test users are able to trigger their personal site creation. Ironically, when I repeat on a rtm farm I don't see this issue.

- Web App created with host header `http://my.domain.com`
- SC host created with same url and `SPSMSITEHOST#0` template
- Managed paths for "my" (explicit) and "personal" (wildcard)
- Check service applications connection for My Site: Managed Metadata, Search and User  -  - Profile Service. Also checked the service connection and ran a profile sync
- Created new Permission Policy "Create My Site"
- Created an new User Policy: All zones, Everyone and "Create My Site"
- Self Service Site Create: I have tried both the "hidden from users" and prompt users: http://my.domain.com/[personal]

Out of intestest I wonder what are the implications of my lack of MySites e.g. will this affect where my previous personal search queries are stored?

Comment: Have you checked the ULS logs? Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your reply. I literally solved this an hour ago.

I went into CA -monitoring loggins and diagnostic logging

Then I saw this:

> Skipping creation of personal site from
>   MySitePersonalSiteUpgradeOnNavigationWebPart::CreatePersonalSite()
>   because one or more of the creation criteria has not been met. [SPWeb
>   Url=http://my.mydomain.com/Person.aspx?accountname=WSLDEV\Danielw] 
>   http://my.mydoamin.com/Person.aspx?accountname=WSLDEV\Danielw]Self-Service
>   Site Creation == True  Can Create Personal Site == False  Is **user
>   licensed == False**  Storage&Social UPA Permission == True  Site or
>   Page or Web Part is in design mode == False

Now it appears somehow that my install had users configured with Foundation lic even though

```
 PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-SPUserLicense

 License                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  -------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 Enterprise                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 Standard                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 Project                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 OfficeWebAppsEdit
```

Confusing I know. So what I had to do is follow [Configure licensing in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219627.aspx). Thanks to Paul Stork, MVP for pointing this out although I am still confused as to why this was needed to done as it shouldn't by default